# Recall method until return true

Tags: c#

I've a condition where I want to call a method until it return true, if return true then go to next statement otherwise recall itself

```
     var username= GetUniqueUserName();
     if(UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username))
     {
                   // next statement
     }
     else
     {
      // recall CheckUser               

     }
```

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. (out of context that is)

Comment: @asawyer alternative ??

Comment: What would make `UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username)` return a different result on a further call ?

Comment: @SizS I don't know and you didn't post what you are **actually** trying to accomplish. This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Consider though a situation where your condition will never be met, outside of your applications control. How should your software respond? "Enter an infinite loop" hardly seems like the correct answer.

Comment: All above AND if 'GetUniqueUserName' returns a UNIQUE username, why would CheckUserName ever return that it's taken?!?

Answer (score 2):

you can

```
while(UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username))
{
   //code inside, if you need some, if not just leave this blank
}


//something after `CheckUserName` returned false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` instead of an `if`.  (And NOT the condition.)

Answer (score -1):

With a recursive implementation :

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    var username= GetUniqueUserName();
    MyImplementation(username);
}

private void MyImplementation(string userName)
{
    if (!UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username))
    {
        MyImplementation(userName);
        return;
    }

    //actual stuff here
}
```

With an iterative implementation, your application might fall into an infinite loop, having a thread permanently asking the same question to UtilityRepository, as @asawyer pointed out. With a recursive implementation, you'll presumably run into a StackOverflowException. Both cases are rather unsatisfying. Could you upgrade `UtilityRepository` to get a notification when "the status of username has changed" ?

Comment: Not sure how crashing the stack is a better solution to be honest.

Comment: There are much, much better ways of ensuring a maximum number of attempted iterations, if that is a requirement of the program.

Comment: @Servy: For sure, but that's not specified in the question.

Comment: @Seb Exactly, so why are you posting an answer to solve a problem that's not even in the question in the first place?

Comment: @asawyer: both "solutions" are inappropriate in a real world application.

Comment: @Servy: lol. I'm precisely answering the question. I do not judge if the question is relevant or not.

Comment: @Seb Then why are you proposing it, if you know it's inappropriate?  Why did you not suggest an *appropriate* solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50139/discussion-between-seb-and-servy)

Answer (score -2):

```
var username= GetUniqueUserName();
while ( UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username) )
{
    //recall user
}
// next statement
```

OR more charged, but with the same functionality way:

```
var username= GetUniqueUserName();
bool flag = true;
while ( flag )
{
     if(UtilityRepository.CheckUserName(username))
     {
          // next statement
          flag = false;
     }
     else
     {
          // recall CheckUser               
     }
}
```

But it looks horrible, I think you should divide your `.CheckUserName` method into two or more separated methods, so u do not need to left blank space on `// recall Chechuser` .

Comment: Why would you ever use the second approach, given that it functions identically to the first?

Comment: @Servy I would never :) Just wanted to explain to an author what's going on and why they are same more clearly ...

Comment: If you're trying to explain what a `while` does, then you shouldn't use a `while` loop in your definition.

Comment: @Servy Ok, you know better. I just know that when I ask easy question, but for me it's not understandable, I would prefer as simple and chewed answer as possible ..

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is meant by `sophisticated` here? I don't understand.

Comment: @asawyer you could observe that second approach is doing absolutely the same things, but all these declarations like 'flag' and so on take more space etc.

Comment: Adding extra declarations that take more space but don't accomplish anything is not exactly what I would consider 'sophisticated'

Comment: @asawyer I changed it to a "charged". Thank you for criticism.